# question on finding limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Let
$x_n=\left(1-\frac13\right)^2\left(1-\frac16\right)^2\left(1-\frac1{10}\right)^2.....\left(1-\frac1{\frac{n(n+1)}2}\right)^2,n\ge2$
then find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}~ x_n$  ?

while answering please mention the underlying concept too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Try rewriting the expression
$$1-\frac1{\frac{n(n+1)}2}$$
in the form
$$\frac{(n+a)(n+b)}{(n+c)(n+d)}$$
for constants $a,b,c$ and $d$.

Comment: well how and why is it done?

Comment: Since you are looking for an infinite product, it is a good idea to rewrite every factor itself as a product. I understand the reason may not be very clear to you, but try and see: you will get something very interesting.

Comment: it is still unclear.

Comment: Which values do you get for $a,b,c$ and $d$?

Comment: i dont know how to proceed.

Comment: i think i got the form, so constants a=2, b=-1,c=0 and d=1.

Comment: whats the next step

Comment: That's correct. The fact that $a,b,c,d$ are integers is interesting. Imagine writing down $x_n$ using this. In the numerator there's a product of $(k+2)^2(k-1)^2$ for $k$ from $2$ to $n$, and in the numerator there's a product of $k^2(k+1)^2$ for $k$ from $2$ to $n$.

Note that most of the factors will appear in both numerator and denominator, which makes them disappear.

Now it's left to find out which factors do not cancel. This allows you to write $x_n$ in a simple form, for $n>3$.

Comment: Take for example $n=10$. In the numerator, $4^2$ will appear when $k=2$ (due to the factor $(k+2)^2$) and when $k=5$ (due to $(k-1)^2$). In the denominator $4^2$ will appear as $k^2$ when $k=4$ and as $(k+1)^2$ when $k=3$. All this together makes these factors $4^2$ disappear. The same holds for the factors $5^2$, $6^2$, $7^2$, $8^2$ and $9^2$. Not for $10^2$, since in the numerator there won't be a $k$ s.t. $k-1=10$. Neither will it work for $3^2$, because in the numerator there won't be any $k$ s.t. $k+2=3$.

Comment: thanks for such a explanatory answer, i hadn't expected such effort to make it so clear

Comment: btw the answer comes out to be 1/3

Comment: $\frac13$ seems correct to me. I hope you have learned something from this. P.s: this strategy to simplify a product or sum by 'combining factors or terms', is sometimes called 'telescoping'. Maybe take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series. This technique can be used in some special cases like this.

Comment: u seem to be a fantastic person

Comment: do you know some more strategies?where can i find these